# How to display database URL as web page URL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have created a web application in php.
I display database record on web page with id.
My current URL look like below.

`example.com/post.php?id=1`

Now, I getting all column's value from database where my ID is equal 1
In my database Column URL value on row 1 like below.
my-first-page.php
I want to display URL like below.

`example.com/my-first-page.php?id=1`

I want to do this via htaccess file
Please experts help me how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(post\.php)$ /my-first-page.php [L,R=301,NC]
```